# How to precise control the position of the inline graphic in Sprak RichEditableText

Tags: apache-flex, position, alignment, flex4.5, richeditabletext

At the moment, I use the property `alignmentBaseline` to set the alignment of inline graphic and text, but it can't control the position precisely and it seems strange.

In HTML, I can control it by CSS property padding or margin. How should I do it in flex4.5?